# count number of rows associated with their id in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi We have 3 Table of a music which is something like this in MySql :

**1st Table :**

the first table is for `playlist` table where music playlist is exist.

```
playlistId           playlistTitle          categoryId

1                    hello                  0
2                    wow                    0
3                    wi-fi                  0
4                    awesome                0
5                    sixer                  1
6                    four                   1
7                    boundary               2
```

**2nd Table :**

2nd table is for `songRelation` table where every playlist is associated with thier song

```
playlistId            songId

1                     4
1                     3
1                     43
1                     57
1                     98
2                     56
2                     67
2                     90
2                     78
3                     98
3                     78
3                     89
43                    90
```

**3rd Table :** the 3rd table is for `song` table where song detail exist

```
songId                songTitle

4                     hello
3                     real hero
43                    singalone
57                    awesom
98                    really
78                    sakaka
98                    shikwa
89                    moha
90                    hello2
67                    Sneh
```

actually i am fetching the result something like this:

```
playlistId  songId    categoryId songTitle

1           4         0          hello
1           3         0          real hero
2           56        0          singalone
2           67        0          Sneh
3           78        0          sakaka
3           98        0          Shikwa
```

where the every `playlistId will be with their first 2`songId`and with their`categoryId`and also with`songTitle`.

but i want to count the total `song` with every `playlistId`

after getting the total song result i want will be something like this :

```
playlistId  songId    categoryId songTitle       totalSong

1           4         0          hello           5
1           3         0          real hero       5
2           56        0          singalone       4
2           67        0          Sneh            4
3           78        0          sakaka          3
3           98        0          Shikwa          3
```

here is the jsfiddle Demo where query is without `totalSong` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eda7/5

What subquery will be added to get the above desired result.

Comment: `select playlistid, count(songid) from playlist group by playlistid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this query to ur [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eda7/22).

```
SELECT p.playlistId, s.songId, p.categoryId, s.songTitle,
    (select count(sr1.songId) from songRelation sr1 
     where sr1.playlistid=p.playlistid 
     group by sr1.playlistId) as total,
       @r := IF (@pid = p.playlistId,
                 IF (@pid := p.playlistId, @r+1, @r+1),
                 IF (@pid := p.playlistId, 1, 1)) AS rn
FROM playlist AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0, @pid:=0) AS vars
INNER JOIN songRelation AS sr ON p.playlistId = sr.playlistId
INNER JOIN song AS s ON sr.songid = s.songid
ORDER BY p.playlistId, s.songId ) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```

It is giving the required output. Check the [Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eda7/22)

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly the result you asked, use this:

```
select p.playlistId, 
       s.songId, 
       p.categoryId, 
       s.songTitle, 
       (select count(*) from songRelation where playlistId = p.playlistId) totalSong
from playlist p 
inner join songRelation r on p.playlistId = r.playlistId
inner join song s on r.songId = s.songId
```

Using a group by on the main query would merge the detailed song data, forcing you to run two queries: one for details (first 4 fields) and a second query, to recover the totals (last column). Using this solution, you get all detailed data and totals, the sub-query will recover the count of songs for each playlist, the way you asked.

**UPDATE:**

This way, suggested by rlanvin, should make the query faster, because instead on computing the subquery for each row, it gets computed only once, and then is joined to the main query. The result is the same:

```
select p.playlistId, 
       s.songId, 
       p.categoryId, 
       s.songTitle, 
       r1.totalSong
from playlist p 
inner join songRelation r on p.playlistId = r.playlistId
inner join song s on r.songId = s.songId
inner join (SELECT playlistid, COUNT(songId) as totalSong from songRelation group by playlistid) r1 on p.playlistId = r1.playlistId
```

Comment: It would probably be faster to move the subquery as a join like this : `SELECT p.playlistId, [...] c.totalSong FROM playlist p JOIN (SELECT playlistid, COUNT(songId) as totalSong From songRelation) AS c ON c.playlistid = p.playlistId JOIN songRelation ...`. Tough the fastest way would be to add a field `totalSong` in the `playlist` table and update it whenever a song is added/removed.

Comment: @rlanvin, I considered this, it's much better to replace the table with a query, than to put a sub-query in the field list. However, replacing the songRelation table with this query would remove the songId field from it, and songId is necessary for the subsequent join: inner join song s on r.songId = s.songId. Do you see a way around this?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to replace any of the joins in your query, just adding a new one with the subquery.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong! Indeed, this change should increase performance, I will update the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Group Functions you can do this:

```
SELECT `playlistid`, COUNT(`songid`)
  FROM `playlist`
  GROUP BY `playlistid`
```